# Can I send a body using wp_remote_get()?

Tags: plugins, php, api

I'm writing a WordPress plugin and want to retrieve data from my API on another domain using wp_remote_get()

On this page:
https://wp-kama.com/function/wp_remote_get

There is a Usage Template:

```
$remote_get = wp_remote_get( $url, array(
    'timeout'     => 5,
    'redirection' => 5,
    'httpversion' => '1.0',
    'user-agent'  => 'WordPress/' . $wp_version . '; ' . get_bloginfo( 'url' ),
    'blocking'    => true,
    'headers'     => array(),
    'cookies'     => array(),
    'body'        => null,
    'compress'    => false,
    'decompress'  => true,
    'sslverify'   => true,
    'stream'      => false,
    'filename'    => null
) );
```

The default for the 'body' argument is null, but the fact that it's present suggests to me that one can use it.  But when I set it to a string, like this, the call fails.

```
$response = wp_remote_get( $api_endpoint, array(
    'headers' => array(
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'X-Public' => $api_public_key,
        'X-Hash' => $contentHash,
    ),
    'body' => $body,
));
```

I get the error:

> TypeError: http_build_query(): Argument #1 ($data) must be of type array, string given in /var/www/html/wp-includes/Requests/src/Transport/Curl.php on line 578

[image]

(don't worry that I included keys, etc in the above image - they are only temporary test keys)

My question is, am I able to send a body using wp_remote_get(), and, if so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Putting a body in as a query parameter is probably just polluting your access logs. Just use `wp_remote_post()`. POST method requests aren't just for write operations.

Answer (score 2):

I think I've figured out the solution.

The short answer is GET requests don't usually have a body, but wp_remote_get() will take what one assigns to the body argument and make it into URL parameters.  That's why it expects an array (because each element of the array becomes a parameter added to the URL).

One solution is to simply wrap the "body" in an "array()", like this:

```
"body" => array($body),
```

and then retrieve the body on the receiving end as the first request parameter.

Comment: Note that GET requests can technically have a body, but that kind of goes against the purpose of GET requests that they should be cacheable and you should get a consistent response per URL. So many tools convert the body to URL parameters, like JQuery's ajax too. But it's possible in Postman and should work